# @Html.HiddenFor() does not retain value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field, html.hiddenfor

in my view all data is coming from viewmodel
and the viewmodel consist of following:

```
  public class Coursework
{
   public virtual PortfolioMaster prtfMaster { get; set; }
   public virtual bool uploadfile { get; set; }
    public virtual string filename { get; set; }
}
```

when i use this in my view as shown:

```
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.prtfMaster.CourseID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.filename) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.uploadfile)
```

it is not retaining value for `filename` and `uploadfile`
but in my view if i use `@if(Model.uploadfile)` it is giving me appropriate value

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
How can i retain the value of `model.filename`

Comment: The lack of punctuation is making this difficult to read.

Comment: are you passing an instance of the Coursework object to the view? can you show us how you implement your model binding?

Comment: @hallie : yes i'm passing the object to the view

Comment: @kubal5003Sorry for my poor english

Comment: what you mean by not reatining the value ? You are setting the value in your get action and it is not available in the view ? or you dont get it in your post action ? show more code pls

Comment: @Shyju: i'm setting value in the controller for my filename and when i try to get it on view, it is showing null in the viewsource
Also i'm trying to fetch this value in the same post action 2nd time, there it is giving me ""